# Using JavaScript in a Strongly typed view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view as following:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form</legend>
        <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Nombre) </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Name)
        </div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Ape1) </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Ape1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Ape1)
        </div>            

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email) </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email)
        </div>
        <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password) </div>
        <div>
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create user" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and i need to add another field where the user enters again the password, and then, when the user clicks the button "Create user" i want to check if both fields => u.Password and the new one, have the same value, and if so go ahead and if not then display a message in the view (not as a alert).

sorry for my english and thx in advance

Comment: Answering would require creating a solution for you. You should give us descriptions of your previous attempts (including choices of framework or "raw" JavaScript) and a specific problem.

Comment: Just add another property to your view model `ConfirmPassword` and add the `Compare` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OP is asking for JavaScript though.

Comment: @OskarLindberg, Which is why its a comment not an answer (and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` is javascript)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know the consequences of your suggestion and that they may include JavaScript under the assumption that the OP are using a standard template with a certain configuration. I don't think the OP does though. I think you're comment is good in that it provides an arguably better solution (education), I just think it may also mislead people to the assumption that there _is_ no JavaScript solution.

Comment: @OskarLindberg, No where in my comment have I stated there  is _no Javascript solution_.

Answer (score 1):

Add another property ‘ConfirmPassword’ like below in your model and use that property.

Use '[Compare]' for comparing two passwords.

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

please create an MVC3 empty project (internet Allication). Which have sample code.

Comment: Thanks all for your approach , i am starting learning this world and i wanted to try if there was an easy way to use javascript in this context, but as i see i will have to create a new property.

Comment: @Veelicus, This appears to be a 'Register User` form. Without having the extra property, so would not be able to do server side validation on one of the most important parts of your app.

Comment: you are right, but what i want is to check if both passwords are the same in the client side, and if they are, then send all data to server where i check against DataBase if the information is correct.